# Include source files on a per-configuration basis in CMake

Tags: cmake

In my particular CMake project, I have three C++ files:

```
a.cpp
b.cpp
c.cpp
```

I want 'a.cpp' to be compiled in all configurations (release & debug).
I only want 'b.cpp' to be compiled in DEBUG configuration.
I only want 'c.cpp' to be compiled in RELEASE configuration.

How can I do this? I need something similar to the `debug` and `optimized` keywords that are accepted by the `target_link_libraries()` CMake operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know cmake does not provide a way to exclude some files based on configuration. So you need a workaround to achieve this behavior.

For example, you can wrap the whole content of `b.cpp` and `c.cpp` with some guard macro:

```
#ifdef BUILD_ME
//original content of your file
#endif
```

and next set configuration-specific compiler definitions in cmake:

```
if (${CMAKE_GENERATOR} MATCHES "Make" AND "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "")
    # This block might be needed because CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is usually
    # undefined for makefiles.
    # And COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE are not chosen by default.
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE)
endif()

set_source_files_properties(b.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG BUILD_ME )
set_source_files_properties(c.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE BUILD_ME )
add_executable(target_name a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `$<CONFIG:cfgs>` generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:CONFIG) in your call to [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html), [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html), or [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html). Ex.

```
add_executable(my_target
  a.cpp
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:b.cpp>
  $<$<CONFIG:Release>:c.cpp>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This this issue has been fixed as of 3.17:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.17.html#generators

"Visual Studio Generators learned to support per-config sources. Previously only Command-Line Build Tool Generators supported them."