# How to add Debug source files in visual studio cmake projects?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

How to add  Debug source files in visual studio cmake projects?
I know that sln projects can add in the solution properties, so how to add in cmake projects?
I guess it should be set in launch.vs.json, but I don't know the keyword or format.
[details for questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUn5n.png)

Comment: what's a "debug source file"?

Comment: For example , I want to add Qt source files to my cmake project just convenient for debug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include source files on a per-configuration basis in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667209/include-source-files-on-a-per-configuration-basis-in-cmake)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to add the source files for the debug version of a library that isn't built by your cmake project, but just comes with `.pdb` files or something else?

Comment: Here thank you first, in case you do not understand my meaning, I have added a description picture above.

Comment: please avoid solely relying on usage of images to convey what can also be conveyed in textual form (see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541)